# How to show a live preview of a markdown cell's output while editing it in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown, ipython

Markdown Cells in Google Colab shows the output of markdown cells while editing itself

[image]

Markdown Cells in VS Code don't show the output of markdown while editing markdown but colab shows it while editing as shown above

[image]

I want to see the markdown output while editing it in VS Code like in colab. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to use the command `View: Split Editor`, then edit the cell in one half, and render the markdown in the other half. [image]

Comment: "Almost" answered my question but is it possible to make the preview view below the editor, instead of side by side (like in the question)?

Comment: @VVY use the command "View: Split Editor into Group Below"

Answer (score 1):

I googled "`github vscode issues jupyter preview markdown while writing`" and found this issue ticket in the `microsoft/vscode-jupyter` GitHub repo: [[Feature Request] Render Markdown text realtime #1340](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1340), which covers what you are asking for. Unfortunately, it was closed in October of 2021 with [the message](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1340#issuecomment-946205323):

> Thanks for the feedback! However, we don't have plans on adding this functionality at this time.

You could try your hand at raising it again.

Note: Another failed attempt was made: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13992.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly edit the `.md` file, and click the button in the upper right corner to open the preview window.

[image]

Comment: my question is for jupyter notebooks in vscode i.e .ipynb files in vscode, not .md files